# How to get the count of a field using AWK?

Tags: linux, shell, networking, awk

i am facing challenge on to get the number of logs from a file from specific ip.

The logs look like:

```
Apr 24 16:00:28 192.168.5.5 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]

Apr 24 16:00:28 192.168.5.6 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]
```

i am using below command to get the count from ip 192.168.5.5 for "Apr 24"

```
# zcat filename | grep "Apr 24" | awk '{print $4}' | grep "192.168.5.5" | wc -l
```

I tried with the above command and i got the result but i am not sure the result is correct.

Please add your comments if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try each part of your pipeline one by one.  The first part prints only the IP.  The second part greps for a date.  It should be obvious why no results match.

Comment: If your `awk` only prints field 4, your `grep` will no longer able to find `Apr 24`...

Comment: A single `awk` is enough for this job - no need for 2 `grep`s and a `wc`

Comment: i have made some changes in the question, kindly check.

Comment: Try `zcat ... | awk '/Apr 24/ && /192\.168\.5\.5/ {print {$4}'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell just add anchors or make it string comparisons and test on specific fields (you don't want `192.168.5.5` matching on `192.168.5.50` or matching on where it occurs mid-line `inside/192.168.5.5(1039)` or something, and so when the OP wants to search for `Apr 2` she doesn't match on `Apr 20`, etc.) and that's the right way to do it - zcat piped to a single awk command with compound conditions.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried with "zcat filename | awk '/Apr 24/ && /192\.168\.5\.5/ {print $4}' | wc -l  " but command is not giving me any OP. it's running from past 20 minutes.

Comment: @Nikhil.J then that's about how long your `zcat` takes. The awk impact will be negligible and the wc is just waiting till it's collected all of its input to be able to produce output. Have you tried the script without the final pipe to `wc -l` to check that it's producing the output you expect?

Comment: @EdMorton Feel free to go ahead and answer comprehensively - I was only nudging in the right direction...

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, you gave the OP enough to start with, I was just chiming in with some additional info she might not have considered.

Answer (score 2):

awk is a good tool but this can be resolved using grep only. try the following.

zcat filename | grep "Apr 24" | grep "192.168.5.5 :" | wc -l

Comment: Why would you use 2 calls to grep, 1 call to wc and 2 pipes instead of just 1 call to awk though? Your script is equivalent to `zcat filename | awk '/Apr 24/ && /192.168.5.5 :/{c++} END{print c+0}'` which could be made more robust with slightly different awk code but you're out of luck with a multi-grep approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , but what if the ip matches in log messages for e.g "access-list inside denied udp inside/192.168.5.5(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0] "

Comment: you can combine the two grep also. like `zcat filename | grep "Apr 24.*192.168.5.5 :" | wc -l `, this will also work as per your file pattern.

Comment: again more simple and efficient way is `grep "Apr 24.*192.168.5.5 :" filename | wc -l`